# Append variable to partial name in handlebars (mustache)

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache, gruntjs

I am using handlebars with grunt assemble, say I have a page that has a data field called 'page', can I pass that data field to the name of a partial (in another partial)?

Eg:

- A page has the 'page' field with the value of 'dashboard-one'
- The partial 'sidebar', that has wrapping mark-up, calls another partial `{{ sidebar-*dashboard-one* }}` where *dashboard-one* is the variable above that is passed in from the page
- This means that every page that needs a sidebar can have an associated partial called 'sidebar-dashboard-one', 'sidebar-dashboard-two' etc

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass variable as partial name usual way. There is two possible solutions:

1) If you know all possible names you can statically generate flat template and use it as you want.

Initial data:

```
{
    "names": [
        { "name": "dashboard-one" },
        { "name": "dashboard-two" }
    ]
}
```

Static template:

```
{{#each names}}
    \{{#if name.{{name}} }}
        \{{> sidebar-{{name}} }}
    \{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

will produce:

```
{{#if dashboard-one }}
    {{> sidebar-dashboard-one }}
{{/if}}

{{#if dashboard-two }}
    {{> sidebar-dashboard-two }}
{{/if}}
```

Then you pass name 'dashboard-one' in template context:

```
{ "name": "dashboard-one" }
```

and get partial `sidebar-dashboard-one` executed.

2) Write custom helper. Handlebars internally use method `Handlebars.VM.invokePartial` to invoke partials. [See, how it works](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/085e5e1937b442a4d4add5525db2627e825538aa/lib/handlebars/runtime.js#L34).